# How to import cors modules in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am experiencing some issues when trying to import the `cors` module in an Express + TypeScript project.

If I write:

```
import cors from "cors";
```

I got the following message:

`"Cannot find module 'cors'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?"`

How can I fix that?

[Edited]:
BTW, I tried adding the moduleResolution option to my tsconfig.json and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message suggests?

Comment: add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to your tsconfg

Comment: @bogdanoff yeah I tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: @AxelSomersethCordova whats error message now, it can't be same as prev. Also restart `tsc` just in case.

Comment: @bogdanoff 

I found a solution. I added it as a response to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by installing the "@types/cors" package.

I was migrating a JavaScript Node.js Server to TypeScript.

I was following this guide: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#writing-a-configuration-file

Apparently, I must import all types from the packages I am using.